# SQL Connection between console app running on my local machine and RDS service of AWS

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-ec2

Hi I am new on AWS i have created RDS service and in inbond I whitelisted only my organization IP and in outbound I set all. I have a console app(based on .net core) which set connection with RDS and get and set the records, It is working fine for me(I am using my organization desktop). But when i deliver this app to client and he runs on his desktop it failed to get a single record.

So i was wondering, is it necessary to whitelist the client IP in inbond of AWS?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the client IP in inbond of AWS

For direct connection, yes. If you allowed `inbound` connections to RDS instance only from your IP and your work/home, no other IP will be able to connect to it directly.

But for indirect connections, you can setup VPN or ssh tunnels through some bastion instance in the save VPC as your RDS. This way, all connections can go through the bastion instance, and there is no reason to expose your RDS to the internet.